# How can I insert a span tag inside of a dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So I have this html code i'm trying to replicate using dom manipulation

```
<h1 id="intro-text">
    HAMADILYTICAL<span id="word">Grill</span>
</h1>
```

I have some styling for that specific span so that it doesn't render in the same line.
This is what I tried but it's obviously not going to work because I'm appending the child after that node not inside of it.

```
// main content
const mainContent = document.createElement('div');
const introText = document.createElement('h1');
const span = document.createElement('span');
mainContent.className = 'main-content';
introText.id = 'intro-text';
span.id = 'word';
introText.textContent = `HAMADILYTICAL Grill`;
content.appendChild(mainContent);
mainContent.appendChild(introText);
introText.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: You have to style the `<span>` somehow; nothing in the code you posted appears to make any attempt to do that. CSS does not care about the order in which things are added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using innerHTML fixed it

```
const mainContent = document.createElement('div');
const introText = document.createElement('h1');
mainContent.className = 'main-content';
introText.id = 'intro-text';
introText.innerHTML = `<h1 id="intro-text">
HAMADILYTICAL <span id="word">Grill</span></h1>`;
content.appendChild(mainContent);
mainContent.appendChild(introText);
```